# Add local Composer to PATH

Tags: php, bash, laravel, path, composer-php

I have installed Composer locally only for one Laravel project

```
~/phpstorm/myproject/composer.phar
```

and didn't have any problem till I tried to create a new Laravel project, then I got an error:

> Could not open input file: composer.phar

I tried to add the .phar file directly to the PATH, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
PATH=~/phpstorm/myproject/composer.phar:$PATH
```

Does somebody know how I could manage this problem without installing Composer globally? In the Internet I only found this easiest kind of solution, but it doesn't suit me, alas.

Thanks for your proposals in advance!

Comment: why not installed globally?

Comment: You should get rid of composer.phar from the path (e.g. `PATH=~/phpstorm/myproject/:$PATH`)

Comment: Saying that, that's probably not what you want. Move it to /usr/local/bin/ and add that to your path instead.

Comment: Thank you Farkie that helped. I didn't want to install composer globally, because Laravel can't use it anyway. Furthermore I habe some issues with permissions on my host, so that I need everytime to ask support to install something globally and it's weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name from composer.phar to composer by this command:
`mv composer.phar composer`, give it execution permissions by running the following: `chmod 0755 composer` or `chmod a+x composer`, and put the current path to the PATH env variable in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file, restart your terminal and it should work, or you can always install it globally. Bests! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another, easy option would be to create an alias for it in your shell

eg for bash:

```
alias composer='php ~/phpstorm/myproject/composer.phar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add composer to your path unless you want to use it globally. You can just do

```
php composer.phar
```

Comment: well, when I do `laravel new project` it takes by default the global one